# UINavigationBar covers UITableView when dismissing UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a UINavigationBar with a search button. The search button triggers a UISearchController:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

When a user selects a search result, a new ViewController is pushed. If the user then taps back they are presented with the old ViewController with the still active search results.

If they then tap Cancel to dismiss the UISearchController, the UINavigationBar now covers the content in the view. I think it may be my setting of `self.definesPresentationContext` to `true` in `viewDidLoad` and `false` when the next viewController is presented

[image: Process from left to right]

Answer (score 0):

If you think that you know the cause of the issue, have you tried commenting out those lines? Does it still do it then?

It sounds to me more like something to do with the UIViewController's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property.

Try setting that to `false` on your UIViewController.

EDIT:

Have you tried changing the UIViewController's `edgesForExtendedLayout` property?

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: Commenting out self.definesPresentationContext just breaks the presentation of the searchController, which means I can't replicate it. Setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to false doesn't change the result either - but I suspect it's to do with the UIViewController calculating the insets whilst the searchController is active, even though the UINavigationBar is present throughout.